# groupby filtering in linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

i need a groupby this query

```
if (Randomize)
{
    List<tblInvoice> _Result = db.tblInvoices.ToList();

    var _Temp = xxx.Where(p => (p.isPostalPayment == null || p.isPostalPayment == false)).ToList();
    _Result = _Temp.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5).ToList();
    _Result = _Result.GroupBy(x => x.cUserID).ToList();
    return _Result;
}
```

when i use groupby in query, error
When I use groupby in this query, get the Under error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: That error is not fully quoted, which won't help people figure out your problem.  Christos has worked it out... his answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `_Result` is a `List<tblInvoice>`. So here

```
_Result = _Temp.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5).ToList();
```

you have no problem. You order by your invoices and just you take 5 of them an you create a new `List<tblInvoice>`.

However, here

```
_Result = _Result.GroupBy(x => x.cUserID).ToList();
```

there is a problem. The `GroupBy` return a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` objects and then calling `ToList` you create a list 
of this type of objects and **not** a `List<tblInvoice>`. So you can't assign a reference of a list of this type to a variable that can hold references to `List<tblInvoice>` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Found a new solution to the problem Of course without using groupby!

```
if (Randomize)
{
    List<tblInvoice> _Result = new List<tblInvoice>();
    var _Temp = xxx.Where(p => (p.isPostalPayment == null || p.isPostalPayment == false)).ToList();
    List<long> _UserIDs = new List<long>();
    foreach (var _Row in _Temp.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList())
    {
        if (_Result.Count == 3)
            break;

        if (!_UserIDs.Contains(_Row.ID))
        {
            _UserIDs.Add(_Row.cUserID);
            _Result.Add(_Row);
        }
    }
    return _Result;
}
```